# VBA XMLHttp : Sourcing data from web database, reloading website issue

Tags: excel, vba, xmlhttprequest

Morning everyone,

I'm new to VBA so please don't shout at me to loud ;)

I got a base for my macro from other workbook and I adjusted it to source what I want but found one problem. Website reloading results after couple second (one off event) and macro is sourcing only header of the website witch appears on first loading instead of full report that is appearing on website after reload.

How I can make macro to wait for a reload and then source data instead of sourcing just a header?

I hope I described it well enough. Here is the code:

```
Function pullDataSingleURL(url As String, ws As Worksheet)
    Dim httpRequest As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60      'XML V6.0
    Dim DataObj As New MSForms.DataObject   'Forms 2.0
    
    
    Set httpRequest = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    httpRequest.Open "GET", url, False
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    httpRequest.send ""
                    
    Dim newhour, newminute, newsecond, waittime
    newhour = Hour(Now())
    newminute = Minute(Now())
    newsecond = Second(Now()) + 10
    waittime = TimeSerial(newhour, newminute, newsecond)
    Application.Wait waittime
    Debug.Print httpRequest.Status
    Debug.Print httpRequest.statusText
    
    ' ... after the .send call finishes, you can check the server's response:
    'Debug.Print httpRequest.Status
    'Debug.Print httpRequest.statusText

    DataObj.SetText httpRequest.responseText
    DataObj.PutInClipboard
    DoEvents
    With ws
        .Activate
        .Cells.Clear
        .Cells(1, 1).Select
        .PasteSpecial link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True
    End With
    End Function

Public Sub Getdata()


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("RawData").Visible = True

Dim year, month, day
Dim i

year = ActiveSheet.Range("N6").Value
month = ActiveSheet.Range("N5").Value
day = ActiveSheet.Range("N4").Value

Dim strURL As String
strURL = "https://websitename.com/someotherstuff/spanType=Day&startDateDay=" + year + "%2F" + month + "%2F" + day + "&startDateWeek=" + year + "%2F" + month + "%2F" + day + "&startDateMonth=" + year + "%2F" + month + "%2F" + month + "&maxIntradayDays=1&startDateIntraday=" + year + "%2F" + month + "%2F" + day + "&startHourIntraday=0&startMinuteIntraday=0&endDateIntraday=" + year + "%2F" + month + "%2F" + day + "&endHourIntraday=0&endMinuteIntraday=0"

Call pullDataSingleURL(strURL, Sheets!RawData)

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

End Sub
```

Thank you for all answers

Comment: Is the url public?

Comment: Url is not public that's why changed it